# Field not changed when updating table value in asp.net & SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I created a table named track table and on some user login conditions I inserted initial values on table. Code below

```
var tracktable = new TrackTable
{
    IPAddress = ipadd,
    LastLoginResult = "Failed",
    LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now,
    LoginAttemptStreak = 1, 
    BlockTime = DateTime.Now,
    IsBlocked= "false"
};
model.InsertTrack(tracktable);
```

On user's following logins the database is updated with new values for each fields

```
var tracktable = new TrackTable
{
    IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"],
    LastLoginResult = "Success",
    LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now,
    LoginAttemptStreak = result.LoginAttemptStreak + 1,
    BlockTime = vblocktime, 
    IsBlocked= "true" //not_updating
};
model.Updatetable(ipadd, tracktable);
```

The problem I am facing comes in update part. In update part the column `LastLoginResult` is updated to `Success`. But `IsBlocked` column has no change - it is still "false". I am totally confused. What might be causing this problem?

Comment: Is the IsBlocked field a bit (boolean) datatype?

Comment: No its a string field

Comment: Please paste UpdateTable definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have missed to pass the value for "IsBlocked" variable in Updatetable() method.

Comment: model.Updatetable(ipadd, tracktable);
I'm passing the tracktable fully.

Comment: please check inside Updatetable() method.